# About String immutability in Java

Tags: java, string

First, I know that strings in java are immutable.

I have a question about String immutability:

```
public static void stringReplace (String text) 
{
    text = text.replace ('j' , 'c'); /* Line 5 */
} 
public static void bufferReplace (StringBuffer text) 
{ 
    text = text.append ("c");  /* Line 9 */
} 
public static void main (String args[]) 
{ 
    String textString = new String ("java"); 
    StringBuffer textBuffer = new StringBuffer ("java"); /* Line 14 */
    stringReplace(textString); 
    bufferReplace(textBuffer); 
    System.out.println (textString + textBuffer); //Prints javajavac
}
```

But if we write the following:

```
public static void bufferReplace (StringBuffer text) 
{ 
    text = text.append ("c");  /* Line 9 */
} 
public static void main (String args[]) 
{ 
    String textString = new String ("java"); 
    StringBuffer textBuffer = new StringBuffer ("java"); /* Line 14 */
    textString = textString.replace ('j' , 'c');
    bufferReplace(textBuffer); 
    System.out.println (textString + textBuffer); //Prints cavajavac
}
```

The thing is I expected the first example would print the same as the second printed. the reason is when we pass `textString` to a function we actually pass a reference to `textString`. Now in the function's body another string was produced by `text.replace ('j' , 'c')` and we assigned a reference to that string to the string we passed in.
In the second example I just assign a reference to the string produced by `textString.replace ('j' , 'c');` to `testString`. Why there is so difference?

Follow by that reason, the results must be the same. What's wrong?

Comment: Btw. use StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer if you don't need it to be synchronized.

Comment: @jakub.petr Why it's so important?

Comment: @St.Antario Because `StringBuffer` is much slower than `StringBuilder`

Comment: From such a point of view any class/object may be considered immutable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the second example `textString = textString.replace ('j' , 'c');` happens in your main method, so the `textString` variable is assigned a new `String`, and you see the new `String`'s value when printing your output.

In the first example it doesn't happen, since the call to the `stringReplace` method can't change the `String` reference passed to it. Therefore, the output you see is as if you never called `stringReplace(textString)` at all.

This all boils down to Java being a pass by value language. You can't change an Object reference passed to a method, since that reference is being passed by value. If String wasn't immutable, you could change the String instance passed to the method by calling String methods that change its state (if such methods existed), but you still wouldn't be able to assign a new String reference to the method's parameter and see it reflected in the caller of the method.

Comment: Interesting. It would be good if you provided a normative reference to JLS.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1: *When the method or constructor is invoked (§15.12), the values of the actual argument expressions initialize newly created parameter variables, each of the declared type, before execution of the body of the method or constructor.* Java is pass-by-value.

Comment: @JBNizet If it's pass-by-value why _stringBuffer_ has mutated? It passed by value.

Comment: @St.Antario You are not mutating the StringBuffer reference passed to the method. If you tried to assign anew StringBuffer to the variable passed to the method, the result would be the same as with the method that accepts a String. The difference with StringBuffer is that you can mutate the object that the reference refers to inside the method.

Comment: Because text.append ("c") modifies the internal state of the StringBuffer, whereas text.replace ('j' , 'c') returns a copy of the text string, where j has been replaced by c.

Comment: @JBNizet As far as I understand passing by value means a copy of the passed stringBuffer will be created and modified in the function's body. But the copy doesn't affect to the passed object in any way. What's wrong?

Comment: No. A copy of the **reference** to the StringBuilder is made and passed to the method. So, assigning a new value to the reference doesn't change the original one, but since both references (the original and the copy) point to the same object, changing the state of the object in the method also affects it in the calling method: there is a single object involved.